# How to get metrics on ZODB Conflict Errors?

Tags: plone, zope

1. Is there a way I can log conflict errors only separately?
2. Is there an add-on that would help with this?

I would like to do this as part of fine tuning my ZEO cluster.

Comment: What I would do: 1) do a monkey patch which increases a (Redis) rolling time window counter each time there ConflictError 2) then have a script which pulls this counter to your monitoring system (Munix, Zabbix, ZenOSS) for beautiful graph. Related about counting in time window: http://opensourcehacker.com/2014/07/09/rolling-time-window-counters-with-redis-and-mitigating-botnet-driven-login-attacks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have created a simple Plone product for this.

https://github.com/collective/Products.TrackConflictErrors